# Error computing sum "Infinite expression 1/0 encountered"

Tags: special-functions, summation, assumptions

I am trying  to calculate a symbolic sum.The expression is defined as follows:

```
 Sum[(Zeta[-m]*Pochhammer[m - n - 1, n]*x^m)/m!, {m, 1, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {x > 0, n >= 0, n \[Element] Integers}]
```

[image]
[image]

If I put:

```
(Zeta[-m]*Pochhammer[m - n - 1, n]*x^m)/m! /. m -> 1
(* -(1/12) x Pochhammer[-n, n] *)
```

is Ok.

Any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: If I use an alternate expression in terms of `Binomial[]`, I no longer get an error, but the sum returns unevaluated: `Sum[(Zeta[-m] n! Binomial[m - 2, n] x^m)/m!, {m, 1, Infinity}]`.

Comment: For the `Sum[]`, the algorithm changes it into the version with the `Gamma[]` function, which fails at `m=1`. Unfortunately, staring at `m=2` returns the `Sum[]` unevaluated. Add this to @J.M. 's comment, and I suspect no solution exists. Even though the series does seem to converge.

Comment: ...or if there's one, it's a solution *Mathematica* doesn't know.